# Samsung Galaxy S6 edge scroll stuttering

Tags: 5.1-lollipop, performance, samsung-galaxy-s-6

I have just bought an Samsung Galaxy S6 Edge smartphone. After updating the firmware to 5.1.1 version, which is the latest Android software for this phone at this moment, there are some issues with scrolling through applications.

When scrolling through applications such as Settings, Facebook, Twitter, Google Play Store or the application manager (for multi-tasking) the phone has these small lagg spikes. It stops at a random point (the lagg) and then just continues.

There are a couple of video's that shows this problem.

- [Video 1](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-anfCAhljvA&feature=youtu.be)
- [Video 2](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fZJ9xaa-Hw4&feature=youtu.be)
- [Video 3](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=34xCDdaMQ2k)

My device is not rooted and at most of it's factory default settings. There is no custom themes installed and I've tried disabling some of the "bloatware".

I've read some articles about this same problem, and what I can get from it is that the phone is handling to much background-applications. From what I could have seen, people rooted their phones to fix this problem. But I dont want to do this, because this is a new phone.

I couldn't yet believe this is because the specifications of the phone, because they are alot better then my old phone, which didn't had this issue.

How can I fix this problem without having to root or use 3rd-party applications/tools?

<sub>Note: This problem is not so bad, but for a > €600 phone, this is kind of annoying.</sub>

Comment: Maybe a buffering issue? Although I doubt it if no other S6 Edge users have reported something like this.

Comment: @Joe What do you mean? And yes, but I couldn't find a question/solution for it, so I posted it.

Comment: If the Scroll View (basically what allows you to scroll up and down) is dynamic, it could load parts of the list you're scrolling through dynamically when you need it, and get rid of things you don't. So, if you were at the top of a list you were scrolling through, it would load the entries for the list at the top, then as you scroll down it would load the ones further below and get rid of the ones further up to free up memory for the ones its just loaded below, if that makes sense. This is just a possibility, however I'm not sure if I think it is the issue. Software bugs do happen though.

Comment: @Joe Ofcourse, I understand that, but when buying an > €600 phone, you dont really expect it to be "laggy". My friend has an Galaxy S5 phone (with ofcourse lower specs) and he doesn't experience the issues, doing the exact same thing. He's running android 5.0.2 though. Could this possibly fall under my product warranty?

Comment: No, I completely see your point. Different device too, I'm not sure - if it's an issue with your phone, it might, but if it's a software issue there's not much you can do (I don't think at least). Samsung might not release a patch for this as it isn't much of an issue in their eyes. Do you know any other S6 Edge owners who have the problem? That might help in identifying whether it's just your device or (presumably) all S6 Edges.

Comment: @Joe Do you mean it could be an hardware issue aswell? I'd suppose not, unless the CPU or RAM might be bad. I dont know anyone with the S6 edge device, but i've read alot of articles about it on the internet. What would be more logical, the hardware or the software?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/31021/discussion-between-bas-and-joe).

Comment: Have you tried booting into stock recovery then formatting system and caches? If this is a software issue this might fix the scroll issue. be sure to backup important files on your phone like contacts and messages.

Comment: @Hexxed What do you mean by 'stock recovery'? If this is a hard factory reset, i've done this already.

Comment: @Bas, see this info to know what Hexxed meant by stock recovery: http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/recovery-mode/info / http://www.howtogeek.com/193055/what-is-a-custom-recovery-on-android-and-why-would-i-want-one/